# Linear Algebra Matrix number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to make sure I understand this correctly.

If I have 10 linear equations with 20 unknowns I will have 0 solutions, where as if I have 10 linear equations with 5 unknowns I will have infinite solutions?

Comment: So if they have the same amount it would be 0,1 or infinite as well?

Answer (score 2):

That understanding is overly simplistic.  If you have 10 linear equations with 20 unknowns, you will have either zero or infinitely many solutions.  For example, the first two equations might be $x_1+x_2=1, x_1+x_2=2$.  It doesn't matter what the other 8 equations are, there will be no solutions.

If you have 10 linear equations with 5 unknowns, you may have zero, one, or infinitely many solutions.

In general, a linear system may have zero, one, or infinitely many solutions.  The only way to have exactly one is if there are at least as many equations as unknowns.

Comment: A linear system is not underdetermined if there are at least as many equations as unknowns. In regards to your last sentence, it is only necessary but not sufficient, however, to have as least as many equations as unknowns for the linear system to have a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give some details, and a global view of the situation, which is best understood in terms of *vector spaces* and *linear maps*.

A system of $m$ linear equations in $n$ unknownw can be seen matricially, as an equation:
$$Ax=b,$$
where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and $b$ is a vector in $K^m$, $K$ being the base field (whether $\mathbf Q, \mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$). $A$ represents a linear map:
$$u\colon K^n\longrightarrow K^m.$$
This equation has solution(s) if $b$ is in the *range* of $u$. As the range of $u$ is the subspace of $K^m$ generated by the column vectors of $A$, this means, denoting $Ab$ the matrix $A$ bordered by the column-vector $b$, that
$$\color{red}{\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}Ab}.$$

If $r=\operatorname{rank}A$, we know $r\le\min(m,n)$, and by the *rank-nullity theorem*, the solutions, if any, are an *affine subspace* of $K^n$, of dimension $\color{red}{n-r}$.

In particular, if $m\ge n$, and $A$ has maximal rank ($r=n$) and $Ab$ also has rank $r$, the subspace of solutions has dimension $0$, i.e. there is only $1$ solution.